# Schrodinger Memory Leak - On hpy initialization leak disappears

Tags: python, memory-leaks, guppy

I've noticed my python code has a memory leak, and was in the process of debugging it.  I imported hpy from guppy and initialized it (h = hpy()), the leak vanished.  As soon as that initialization is commented out, the leak returns.  Is there something that happens during hpy initialization that could lead to this?  By my understanding it's only supposed to be a heap monitor, so unless it's calling a garbage collector or something, it shouldn't "fix" my issue.

I was focusing mostly on isolating the memory leak in my code, which I feel comes from an external library I am importing.  Mainly, a compiled software called LAMMPs with Python shared libraries setup.  I tried deleting objects, manually calling the python garbage collector, etc.  I discovered that guppy could be used to help isolate a memory leak, and as such was about to try using it; however, noticed that as soon as I import and initialize guppy, the leak disappeared (effectively making it harder to debug now...).

memory_monitor_code.py

```py
import os
import time


for i in range(10000):
    os.system("free -m | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $3}' >> mem.log")
time.sleep(2)
```

leaky_code.py

```py
from guppy import hpy

# CODE AND STUFFS

def objective():

    # With the addition of this, memory leak is effectively removed.
    h = hpy()

    # CODE AND STUFFS
```

Comment: Ha ha, you mean a Heisenberg leak? Perhaps you were thinking of a Schrodinger Thread. Is it dead or alive?

Comment: Hi perhaps this might be of interest https://benbernardblog.com/tracking-down-a-freaky-python-memory-leak/